# Can one use ridge regression to test hypotheses?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, ridge-regression

Are the parameters (the beta's) that result from a ridge regression interpretable as we normally do with canonical linear regression? Can I use them to test hypothesis? Or is ridge regression something that can be used only for Machine Learning (i.e. prediction) tasks?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen agreed that this is duplicate, but just to fill-in what is implicit: ridge regression is a type of regularization, and inference is used when testing hypotheses